# How to print the old and new value using bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to print numbers in this pattern starting from 7:

```
The start number is 7 and the end number is 14
The start number if 14 and the end number is 21
The start number if 21 and the end number is 28
```

...
up to 70

I am trying to use if inside for loop but not able to get the desires output.

Comment: Please include the code you have so far in the question. It will help us see with what exactly you're struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell programming always allows a vast amount of possible solutions (this is why it is always a crude way to solve problems), but you can try it like this:

```
number=7
while [ "$number" -lt 70 ]
do
  echo -n "The start number is $number"
  number=$((number+7))
  echo " and the end number is $number"
done
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and very simple. Thank you!